# Handle Samsung fingerprint overlay

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, fingerprint

I have an alert dialog, that shows "Incorrect Touch ID, attempts left:$attemptsLeft". Problem that Samsung has a window, that blocks any interactions with the app. Question is, if there is any way to avoid this window, or close alert dialog if next alert dialog appears. Thank you[image]

Answer (score 0):

The correct touch is sliding without leaving or untouching the phone my phone is just like that

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).